# how to remove ionic 4 segment indicator (bottom line)? please let me know

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic-framework, sass

```
  .segment-button-indicator {
        -ms-flex-item-align: end;
        align-self: flex-end;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: var(--indicator-color);
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

I am new to hybrid app development. I have to use ion-segment. There is ion-segment-indicator which indicates  bottom line in ion-segment, so I need to remove it. I can remove from these default css codes, but when I try to customize it's not removing

Answer (score 7):

You cannot remove it, but you can hide it by setting it's color to transparent.

On **theme/variables.scss** add this:

```
ion-segment-button {
  --indicator-color: transparent !important;
  --indicator-color-checked: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put into your scss page

```
  ion-segment-button {
    --color-checked: red;
    --indicator-color: none;
  }
```

- indicator for border bottom
- color for segment active/checked

Answer (score 1):

Please go and paste below code in your **variables.scss** it will work

```scss
.segment-button-checked{
  --border-width:0px;
  --indicator-color-checked: 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
ion-segment-button{
  --indicator-box-shadow: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add addtional class on button to avoid conflict and this style

```css
.YourSegmentClass::part(indicator-background) {
  background-color: #FAB159;
}
```